# Servlet, Spring: share session across multiple servers

Tags: spring, jsp, session, servlets, cluster-computing

Let's say I have a Java Servlet+JSP app using Spring framework and Tomcat 6. This app must be hosted on multiple machines. How can I share the HTTP session across many computers?

I usually get my session using this code:

```
HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
HttpSession session = httpRequest.getSession();
```

Should I use some other kind of session (custom implementation of HttpSession) using a common MySQL db or something? Any idea?

Comment: @zmitrok answer is ok, other approach write everything to database not hold at session, just get from there use it and write db again, in cluster session is a tricky way becasue of multiple node management. Other solutions can be in memory caching like Hazelcast  http://hazelcast.com/ or JCache or http://blog.caucho.com/2009/01/21/resin-40-jcache-distributed-caching/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a shared HTTP session storage you need to override the session manager in the application server that you use. Here is a link for Tomcat 8 to give you an idea - http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/manager.html

To answer the 'should' part of your question - you don't have to. You could use session cookie based 'stickiness' option on your load balancer as an alternative to shared cookie storage.